# what would be the best estimate value of $ \ c \ $ so that the function satisfies Intermediate Value theorem

Tags: calculus

See the below graph of the function $ \ f(x) \ $:

[image]

The what would be the value of $ \ c \ $ so that the function satisfies Intermediate Value theorem in $ \ (0,4) \ $ ?

(i) $ \ c=1 \ $

(ii) $ \ c=3/2 \ $

(iii) $ c=2 \ $

(iv) $ \ c=5/2 \ $

(v) $ \ c=3 \ $

(vi) $ \ c=7/2 \ $

**Answer:**

We know that  instantaneous rate of change of $ \ f \ \ at \ \ c \ $ is equal to the average rate of change of the function $ \ f \ $ which is given by $ \ \frac{f(4)-f(0)}{4-0}  \ \approx \frac{1-5}{4}=-1 $

Thus $ \ f'(c) \approx -1 \ $ and this happens at about $ \ c=2 \in (0,4) \ $ because  at $ \ c=2 \ $ the curve f(x) can be approximated by the line $ \ y=-x \ $

**But I can not find out the correct option for** $ \ c \ $

Help me out

Comment: This is somewhat hard to follow.  First, do you mean the Mean Value Theorem?  Second, it doesn't look like we have any information about the function near $x=0$.  Did you possibly mean to refer to interval $(1,4)$ instead?

Comment: No it is  $ \ (0,4) \ $  given . However what would be the result if $ (1,4) \ $ ?

Comment: Then the problem can not be solved since we have no information about the function near $x=0$.  Did you mean to refer to the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Note:  perhaps your picture is just very inaccurate.  As shown, we have $f(4)=1,f(1)=4, f(2)=2$.  As I say, there is nothing to suggest what $f(0)$ might be.

Comment: Note that the question says the  $ \ best \ \ estimate \ $ to determine

Comment: Did you mean to refer to the Mean Value Theorem?  Not sure why I have to ask that three times.

Comment: Yes we have use mean value theorem also along with best estimation

Comment: The question makes no sense for Intermediate Value theorem so please edit it to Mean value theorem.  There is utterly *no* point in asking of $(0,4)$ when $f(0)$ is not even remotely on the graph.  We don't know what to function is so it could behave in any way on (0,1) [actually the way it is drawn it looks like x=1 is an inflection point and the function is about to greatly change behavior] the (0,4) *must* be a typo.  This problem just doesn't have any point to it otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not find the correct option for $c$". You found $c=2$, and it's option (iii). Are you instead saying that $(iii)$ is not the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a graph of the parabola $f(x) = \frac{(x-4)^2}{3}+1$.
It's easy to check on desmos with the test points $(4,1),(1,4),(3,\approx4/3$). (I'm willing to assume it)

By the way, you should heed the wisdom of the comments. The IVT says that there exists at least point between a & b for an output between f(a) & f(b) for a continuous function.
The MVT, however, says that there is a point whose derivate equals the average slope of the function between two points a & b.

This question refers to the MVT (Mean Value Theorem) (and I'm totally willing to assume this too).

So let's start. If we're finding the 'c' in (0,4), then we need to find the value of the function there. $f(0) = 19/3\,,\; f(4) = 1$

Slope = rise/run = $\frac{f(4)-f(0)}{4-0} = -\frac{16/3}{4} = -4/3$.
We have to find a $c$ such that $f'(c) = -4/3$. So let's derive!

$f'(x) = \frac{2(x-4)}3$

$-\frac43 = \frac{2(x-4)}3$

$-4 = 2x-8$ --> $x=2$

So the answer is (iii) $c=2$